# vb - how to pointers in list items and use items in dictionary?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

```
 Dim all_stations As New List(Of station)
    ..
..

    Dim network As New Dictionary(Of train, List(Of station)
```

I have a network = dictionary of (train, list of station) 
and I have a all_station = list (of station)
... I just want to put a pointer on every station in all_station and take them into the dictionary not creating a new objects 
... just to change any property of one station, the property changes everywhere of the object 
how can that be done

Comment: Just adding stations, queried from list, into dictionary should work without any problem. Objects (stations) are reference types and usually only references (=pointers) are are assigned.

Comment: If your types are classes then there's nothing to do because classes are reference types. If your types are structures then it's not possible, because VB doesn't support pointers.

Comment: station must be class not structure

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for pointers in .NET. Just pick any instance of Station, change its properties and it will be changed everywhere where this instance is referenced.

```
Dim stations1 As New List(Of Station)
Dim stations2 As New List(Of Station)
Dim s As New Station
stations1.Add(s)
stations2.Add(s)
Dim s2 = s
s2.Name = "Changed station"
```

"Changed station" will propagate to both lists and both variables.

Comment: is "s" will propagate to both lists and both variables too ???
I mean if I type s.name = "change station" is that will work too ??